# Laravel homestead laravel-elfinder install error

Tags: php, laravel-5, homestead

I'm using Homestead at localhost. I have followed instructions to install it so I did: `composer require barryvdh/laravel-elfinder` and then run `composer update`, but it throws me this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - intervention/image 2.1.3 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is mi
ssing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.1.2 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    ..
    - intervention/image 2.0.11 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.10 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.1 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.0-beta.2 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinf
o is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.0-beta requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo
is missing from your system.
    - intervention/image 2.0.0 requires ext-fileinfo * -> the requested PHP extension fileinfo is mi
ssing from your system.
    - barryvdh/laravel-elfinder v0.3.2 requires barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver 0.1.x@dev -> sati
sfiable by barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver[0.1.0, 0.1.x-dev].
    - barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver 0.1.0 requires intervention/image ~2.0 -> satisfiable by in
tervention/image[2.0.0, 2.0.0-beta, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14, 2.0
.15, 2.0.16, 2.0.17, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.
1.3].
    - barryvdh/elfinder-flysystem-driver 0.1.x-dev requires intervention/image ~2.0 -> satisfiable b
y intervention/image[2.0.0, 2.0.0-beta, 2.0.0-beta.2, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14,
 2.0.15, 2.0.16, 2.0.17, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2
, 2.1.3].
    - Installation request for barryvdh/laravel-elfinder 0.3.2 -> satisfiable by barryvdh/laravel-el
finder[v0.3.2].
```

What should I do? Haven't found any solution on Google.

Comment: Somewhere you've probably got a `dev-master` requirement in your `composer.json`.

Comment: yup, problem was the dev version of laravel

Comment: Did you follows these instructions? http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead  I don't understand why you need this barryvdh/laravel-elfinder at this stage? OKAY sorry seen your reply :)

Comment: actually I removed it anyway and imported it on my own, but I needed ckeditor

Answer (score 1):

1. go to in your project at command line and run this :

   $ composer require intervention/image
2. go to config/app.php  :

In the $providers array add the service providers for this package.

```
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class
```

3. Add the facade of this package to the $aliases array.

   'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class
4. Windows users: just edit php.ini and uncomment this line:

   extension=php_fileinfo.dll

Remember to restart Apache for new php.ini to take effect.

```
homestead halt
homestead up --provision
```